# Why does Azure Logic App have a 'frequency' setting?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

AFAIK, Azure Logic App can be triggered on events (eg: creation of a record in Dynamics CRM).

1. If Logic Apps is triggered based on an event, why do we need a 'frequency' field?
2. I understand that as the frequency increases (check every minute instead of checking every hour), the costs increase. Is that right?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, this is still not an 'event', more something of a 'pulling event' from Azure. Logic apps will look for new items in this case. Hence you only set how often the trigger will do the pull event which you pay for every time it is triggered.

Comment: Thanks! 
I guess the connectors I have been using all having a polling mechanism, rather than a push trigger mechanism.

Comment: Not necessarily, check this link for some more information about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers All thought, last time I used the Dynamics connector it was polling. As it could take ages for the logic app to fire after a record was created in Dynamics.